# MetaTrader4 Terminal, Strategy Tester: how to jump from a [ Results Window ] to the [ Graph ] BEFORE a Trade Happens?

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

I use the MetaTrader Terminal 4, the Strategy Tester, to optimize an Expert Advisor.

After a strategy run, I am looking at the individual trades that were executed in that backtest. I jump from the `Results` sub-window at the bottom of the screen to the referring candle stick in the main chart.

After jumping to the candle stick chart, the chart shows the referring actions ( `sell stop`, `sell`, `t/p` ) at the ***left side*** of the chart.

### Question:

How is it possible to have the chart ***centered around these actions*** or to have the chart showing these actions at the ***right side*** of the time window?

[image: screenshot from Metatrader 4]

Answer (score 0):

Your operation starts at 15:00 and the graph candle you are pointing is the candle starting at 15:00.

The right of the graph is the future, and the left is the past.
So the graph starts just in time BEFORE the operation happens.

In your graph the left side of the X-Axis is 8 May and the right side of the X-Axis is 12 May.

One issue you could have is that the graph you are showing is H1 (see the left top indication), so you don't have enough time resolution to see the details.  If you use a M1 graph you'll see with more accuracy the entry and exit points of your strategy.

Answer (score 0):

### Facts first

If your wish is to somehow modify an event-handling of the MetaTrader Terminal 4/5, than
( as of 2018-03 ) **the software does not provide you any native tool for making this happen**. Neither the built-in GUI-event processing ( a-mouse-click ), nor the script-based, code-automated, processing has any means, how a user-code would get an ability to change the default result, as described in your post.

---

### Solution

Yet, there is one possibility to get where you want to. One can build an external process, that can communicate with MetaTrader Terminal and thus build your GUI-presentation(s) absolutely free from any hard-wired MT4 Terminal built-ins.

This way you can integrate analytical platforms, that are limited just by one's imagination and/or budget.

As an example, this is an external real-time GUI from an external analytic processing, based on MT4 data and flow of both XTO/NTO-events, yet working inside a tight RT-control-loop, having a RTT latency of ~ < 75 ms per event-processed:
[image]

### This heterogeneous, partially-meshed, fully distributed system uses:

<kbd>**MT4**</kbd> `<->` <kbd>**C/C++**</kbd> `->` <kbd>**MATLAB**</kbd> `->` <kbd>**python2.7**</kbd> `<->` <kbd>**Tkinter**</kbd>

```
^                                     |
|                                     |
+-------------------------------------+
```

So, you can get any precision, down to the per each `QUOTE`-event fidelity analytics, if you need and wish to have it.